# Making SEO friendly URL without ID

Tags: php, .htaccess, seo

I have a following URL:  currently `example.com/user/1` - where i should be `example.com/user/name-city`. The URL I tried so far is: `RewriteRule ^db/user/([a-zA-Z0-9_-]+)/$ list.php?id=$1`

How do I achieve my desired result?

**Update**: A Inique ID will be passed in INPUT URL but will not be shown in output URL>

Answer (score 1):

As I understand, you want to change id to 2 variables - name and city?

The following rule should work as you desire:

```
RewriteRule ^db/user/([a-zA-Z0-9]+)-([a-zA-Z0-9]+)/$ list.php?name=$1&city=$2
```

Comment: I can even pass `Id` for query but in URL I want to show `name` and `city` only.

Comment: So you want to pass 3 parameters in URL, but show only 2 in url?

Comment: @Kock Yes that's the desired output

Comment: I don't think there is a way to pass invisible parameter in the URL. You would have to find user id by name and city in the script, or pass 3rd parameter in the URL.

Also, as far as I know, url like db/user/name-city-id is still SEO friendly, so you should be ok.

Comment: There is a way and sadly I am not finding that Link anyway. Many sites use this pattern.